# Как использовать отклонённую правку как основу собственной правки?

Tags: предложение, поддержка, правки, отклонённые-правки

Иногда бывает, что по различным причинам отклоняют хорошую, верную правку. Хотелось бы использовать исходник отклонённой правки для собственной правки — либо в неизменном виде, либо что-то добавить. Так и труд прошлого редактора не пропадёт, и собственного труда будет потрачено меньше.

Есть ли такая возможность? (Разумеется, кроме copy-paste исходного текста, который может быть очень большим).

Если нет, то хотелось бы получить такую кнопку на странице отклоненной правки.

Аналогичная фича уже работает в истории принятых правок: можно взять любую ревизию и начать её редактировать, а позже применить.

Пример правки, к которой это может относиться: [правка](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/27747), [обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/23950507#23950507)

Comment: Думаю, скопировать не проблема. Переключись во вкладку markdown и оттуда стяни. Отдельной кнопки, кажется, нет.

Comment: Отличная идея! Добавил на доску инициатив. Как только появится новая информация, обязательно отпишусь.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky не было новостей об этом?

Comment: @NickVolynkin Нет, нету новостей, к сожалению.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky зато появилась другая фича: если это последняя правка, то модератор или автор сообщения могут поменять результат проверки, то есть принять отклонённую правку, либо отклонить принятую.